# How to mock the springcontext?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

```
private ServiceImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    reMgr = (ReManager) SpringContext.getBean("reManager");
```

I want to mock this method , this is a private constructor which is initializing the springContext. I am setting the beanfactory through my powermockito test case using beans.xml where I have specified the bean and its classname. Still this method is failing to get the instance of reManager .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because if you want to get an instance of a Spring bean to use it in a test Spring offers testing support that allow you to do exactly that. You can create a Spring context in your tests through AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests class and @ContextConfiguration annotation. I could provide you with an example if this what you're looking for

Comment: sure. I am looking to use powermockito for testing. Can you give me the examples ?

Comment: @pvm14 : It would be great if you give me some useful links too

Comment: Personally, I would change it so you pass an instance of `ReManager` into `ServiceImpl`, that would make testing a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding something but if you are using PowerMockito can't you do something along the lines of:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SpringContext.class) 
public FooTest {    
    @Test
    public void foo() {
        final ReManager manager = Mockito.mock(ReManager.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SpringContext.class);
        Mockito.when(SpringContext.getBean("reManager")).thenReturn(manager);

        ... etc...
    }
}
```

See more information [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) on how to verify static behaviour.

Alternatively... I would change the design so your dependencies are passed to the class under test, e.g.:

```
@Test
public void foo() {
    final ReManager manager = Mockito.mock(ReManager.class);
    final ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl(manager);

    ... etc...
}
```

Then there is no need for PowerMock, your testing becomes easier and there's less coupling between classes.

Comment: As far I know the class 'SpringContext' doesn't exist and the equivalent right one ApplicationContext does not have any static 'getBean' method. So tell me what do you need static testing here for? ;-)

Comment: @pvm14 I'm assuming `SpringContext` is a class created by the questioner... personally I would let Spring inject all the dependencies for me. I agree with you in principle! :-)

Comment: You win ;-). Your absolutely right, as usual, my dyslexia fooled me again and I didn't pay attention to that SpringContext.getBean in the question

Comment: I have a question over here , can we use multiple times PrepareForTest , because I already have PrivateMethodVerification at class level , can I add both for static too ? I am not able to find the static.class under verification package ? whats the package path

Comment: @user2181531 You can specify multiple classes to prepare, e.g. `@PrepareForTest({X.class, Y.class})`. Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/src/test/java/demo/org/powermock/examples/simple/GreeterTest.java) for a full example, packages etc... I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If what you wanna do is creating an instance of a Spring bean in one of your tests you don't need to use powermockito for that. You could do something like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/beans.xml")
public class YourTestJUnit4ContextTest extends  AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

private ReManager reManager;

@Before
public void init() {
    reManager= (ReManager) applicationContext.getBean("reManager");
}

@Test
public void testReManager() {
    // Write here the code for what you wnat to test
}
```

}

beans.xml is the file where you define your application context. The best link I can think right know is this

[Spring Testing Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)

Comment: You could drop the `@Before` - as that will be executed for each test - and just stick `@Autowired` on the `reManager` field instead. :-)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right I was just trying to give an answer using elements that appeared already in the question